# Speed Up the load time for some SQLite data

Tags: sqlite

I have a very simple sqlite table:

```
CREATE TABLE config (id INTEGER primary key, 
                     token VARCHAR(255),
                     value TEXT,
                     date DATETIME)
```

Sometime when the webpage is grabbing the info, it spins and spins, but not all the time. Other pages, static, load quickly on this server.

I have been looking into INDEXing the data. Is this the best way to go about speeding up the query or should I be doing something different? Could this be a server issue? If so, how do I figure it out?

EDIT:

I am getting the data like so:

```
SELECT value 
                  FROM config 
                  WHERE token='%s' 
                  ORDER BY id DESC
                  LIMIT 1
```

The page sometimes loads quick, sometimes slow. Sometimes, just half of the table fills and then it just spins until a refresh.

Thanks!

Comment: What query are you executing? Does the query ever complete?

Comment: Can I assume you have a cache system in front of the database ?

Answer (score 0):

How large is the table? How many requests a second are you getting to it?

You'll probably want to create an index so that look-ups by token are quick. Right now, it has to scan the entire table to find the first row whose token matches your parameter.

```
 CREATE INDEX IX_config_token ON config (token)
```

In general, every different way you query a table might benefit from an index just for that query, and so in practice you often end up with multiple indexes per table.

As an example, if I have a `People` table with a `City` and `FirstName` columns, amongst others, and I want to satisfy these three query cases:

1. Select all people that live in City X
2. Select all people that have FirstName Y
3. Select all people that live in City X AND have FirstName Y

Then I need three separate indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_People_City ON People (City)
CREATE INDEX IX_People_FirstName ON People (FirstName)
CREATE INDEX IX_People_City_FirstName ON People (City, FirstName)
```

If I didn't have the third index, then query case #3 would use the first index to find all people that live in city X and then have to manually scan through that to find people that live in city X and have FirstName Y; it's still better than scanning the entire table, but it's still not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for a great response. I will attempt to get this indexed.